# is there any way to make css gid responsive other than grid template aeas? please tell me where i am making mistake

Tags: css-grid

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNtJa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oxvF.png)**your text**i have to create a layout in css grid there are 4 boxes in ist row there should be three boxes and in second row one box should appear at  2nd column i.e at the center.

i  designed the lAYOUT it worked well when i am adding media queries it is not working properly on mobile devices